# dataframe_image chrome executable not able to be found on your machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Estou executando um script python em um docker container e este é o erro que recebo ao tentar exportar um dataframe como uma imagem com a biblioteca dataframe-image.

`OSError: o executável do Chrome não pode ser encontrado em sua máquina`

Answer (score -1):

O erro que você está enfrentando indica que o dataframe-image está tentando usar o Chrome para renderizar a imagem do dataframe e não conseguiu encontrá-lo na sua máquina.

Para resolver esse problema, você pode seguir os seguintes passos:

1. Verifique se o Chrome está instalado na sua máquina e se a sua
   versão é compatível com a biblioteca dataframe-image.
2. Se o Chrome já estiver instalado, tente adicioná-lo ao PATH do seu
   sistema operacional. Você pode fazer isso definindo a variável de
   ambiente PATH para incluir o diretório que contém o executável do
   Chrome.
3. Se o Chrome não estiver instalado na sua máquina, instale-o e tente
   novamente.

Além disso, você pode tentar configurar a biblioteca dataframe-image para usar um navegador diferente, como o Firefox. Você pode fazer isso definindo a variável de ambiente DATAFRAME_IMAGE_BROWSER para o caminho do executável do navegador desejado.

Por exemplo, se você quiser usar o Firefox, você pode definir a variável DATAFRAME_IMAGE_BROWSER para o caminho do executável do Firefox:

```
import os
os.environ['DATAFRAME_IMAGE_BROWSER'] = '/usr/bin/firefox'  # caminho para o executável do Firefox
```

Depois disso, tente exportar o dataframe novamente.